# iOS view controller two-stage rotation animation crash

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I'm facing a problem that is driving me crazy. I read about it around but I didn't find a solution. I'm developing an application that presents modally the view controllers depending on the device orientation. When the device orientation is face up a TabBarController is presented modally. The TabBarController contains two viewControllers one to show a map and the other one (not yet implemented) is for other purposes. When I change the device orientation the application freezes showing the following messages:

> MobileAR[8642:707] Using two-stage rotation animation. To use the
>   smoother single-stage animation, this application must remove
>   two-stage method implementations.
>
> 2011-12-07 21:47:37.566 MobileAR[8642:707] Using two-stage rotation
>   animation is not supported when rotating more than one view controller
>   or view controllers not the window delegate  The problem that occurs
>   is that when the `loadView:` method of the map view controller

There are no problems with the modal presentation of the controller everything works fine as long as the mapviewcontroller `loadView:` do something else. Here is the code in order to have a better understanding:

If the `loadView:` is in this way:

```
- (void)loadView{

    UIView *faceUpView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 718)];
    self.view = faceUpView;
    [faceUpView release];
    MKMapView *mkMap = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 718)]; 
    mkMap.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    [self.view addSubview:mkMap];
    [mkMap release];
}
```

doesn't generate any problems, the view, thereby the map is properly visualized within the TabBarController.

Instead if in the `loadView:` I initialize a view like this:

```
- (void)loadView{

    //Initialize the MapView
    MapView *mv = [[MapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 718)];
    mv.mapViewController = self;
    self.mMapView = mv;

    //Release of the local variable
    [mv release];    
}
```

it freezes as soon as I put the device "Face Up",even if I leave just the first line:  `MapView *mv = [[MapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 718)];`

Here the implementation of its initializer, MapView.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2; //Set the border of the box
        //State that the subviews are confined within its bounds
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;
        //Initialize the View that contains the map with position and size
       // MKMapView *mv = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-106, -106, BOX_SIDE, BOX_SIDE)]; 
        MKMapView *mv = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT)]; 
        //Set the map as standard map (Not satellite nor Hybrid)
        mv.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
        //Retains the map
        self.mapView = mv;
        //Add the map to the super view
        [self addSubview:mv];
        //Release the map view previously allocated
        [mv release];

    }
    return self;
}
```

I didn't ovverride any of the two-stages rotation method neither the one-stage as I read in some answers.

I really appreciate any help!!!! 
Thank you